# Nginx Rewrite redirection / to a directory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am curently using nginx and I am trying to redirect all request on http://vhost.domain.com to http://vhost.domain.com/world

I've browse some sites but I am too rookie with rewrite to obtain a nice result, could you please gimme me some help?

PS: This is what I've tried for last:

```
location = /world {
  rewrite ^ http://vhost.domain.com$uri permanent;
}
```

Kind Regards,

Half

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
location /world/ {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://vhost.domain.com/world/$1 break;
}
```

The nginx rewrite syntax is like:

> rewrite regexp replacement [flag]

For more info, take a look at [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule). And also do some research about [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't have to use any *location*, just write the below *rewrite* directly within *server*.

```
    rewrite  ^/$  http://vhost.domain.com/world  permanent;
```

Comment: This rewrite looks good but when I applied it I have in my- navigator Erreur 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS) : Trop de redirections

Comment: I guess it should be "^/$" instead of just "/", since the first param is a regexp.